# Why my java ping method only work on my computer? (Windows machines tested)

Tags: java, windows, ping

I coded the following ping function in Java for Windows use, it works perfectly on my own computer.  Unfortunately, I have no idea why, but on other computers (Windows Machines), when I run it, **it returns back "null"**.

Could that be for example blocked by Windows Firewall?
Can it be a problem of Windows version? From XP to windows8, or different language versions?

On my computer, I receive such kind of results : time=19ms TTL=111

Can someone enlighten me please, why does it fail?

```
 private String ping() {

        String ip = "<external IP of a server running, always online>";
        String time = null;
        String pingCommand = "ping " + ip;
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C",pingCommand});
    try {
        Process newProcess = builder.start();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(newProcess.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine = in.readLine();
            while ((inputLine != null)) {
                if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
                    if(inputLine.contains("time")){
                        // Checking for the time only
                        time = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("time"));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                inputLine = in.readLine();
            }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return time; 
}
```

Comment: Do the other computers have the ping command?

Comment: The `other computer` you said are windows machines ?

Comment: What do you see if you read the error stream? `newProcess.getErrorStream()` If you use ProcessBuilder you can combine the output and error streams to make them easier to read.

Comment: In all windows machines have ping tool , as well as in Linux and MAC too have this tool.

Comment: Firewall perhaps (the `ping` command might exist but does it return a result)

Comment: Well Linux might have Ping tool but not the `cmd.exe` which is being invoked here.

Comment: @ Tudor: Yes ping command is available on Windows @ Santosh :Yes I tested it of course on windows machine @Peter Lawrey: I actually am not sure that there is an error, it only returns "null"

Comment: @user1638875 In the catch block, call `ex.printStackTrace()` to print exact error. The error may not be printed on console here.

Comment: What returns null? If its the `in.readLine()` you almost certainly are getting an error message.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I guess he is referring to very `ping()` function. The `time` is initialized to `null` and when exception occurs, a null value is returned.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey & Santosh : I only receive "null", there seems to be no error. Like if the try/catch wasn't take into account, could that be the problem? If yes how can it works on my machine but not on others?

Comment: Running command on alien machines is prosecuted by the sysadmins.

Comment: If you run a program and it writes only to the error stream like "Command not found" it won't throw an exception and unless you read this stream you won't know what went wrong.

Comment: @ Roman C: what do you mean? How can I fix this? @ Peter Lawrey: For testing the error streamed, should I add return in the catch or?

Comment: Could that be a firewall problem, as written above? How to fix it to in case? Because the method returns "null" like if the command wasn't run on the cmd.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey: So, I followed your advice with returning the error in the catch, and there is no error displayed. the method only returns "null"

Comment: Maybe it's due to the fact that after the try/catch, time is not saved, therefore displaying the initial data of time (="null")? Do you think it could comes from that? how to fix it in case?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Runtime class to run Windows command. See this sample;

```
   private String ping() {
       Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();   
       String time = null;
       String pingCommand = "cmd.exe /C ping yourIpAddress";
       try {
            Process newProcess = rt.exec(pingCommand);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                newProcess.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine = in.readLine();
            while ((inputLine != null)) {
                  if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
                     if (inputLine.contains("time")) {
                     // Checking for the time only
                         time = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("time"));
                               break;
                             }
                        }
                    inputLine = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Isn't OP doing the same thing ? How does this answer OPs question ?

Comment: @Santosh see carefully this class, and run yourself. I change user1638875's method.

Comment: You have used `Runtime` where as OP as used `ProcessBuilder` but at the end essentially doing the same thing. Not sure how does this solves OPs problem !

Comment: @ Santosh : Hello, I tested your code and I have the exact same problem. Returned "null".

Comment: Maybe it's due to the fact that after the try/catch, time is not saved, therefore displaying the initial data of time (="null")?

Comment: @Santosh I tested this class on other computers (Windows Machines).It is definitely worked.It returns back not "null". It  is the answer of user1638875's question.

Comment: @ SaiYeYanNaingAye: Well,  it works when I run it on my computer. But when I tried with the built jar file, I got the "null" returned on other computers. It worked on mine even with the jar, but not on the others. I have no idea why, it's really weird?

Comment: @user1638875 If you want to ping your computer from other computer, check your network connection. OR If you want to ping other computer itself, change your ip address to other computer ip address.

Comment: @ SaiYeYanNaingAye: I am simply pinging some external server. So it's not a problem of address, neither connection since I am on the same ISP and rooter with the other computers. Maybe It's just like that after the test in the try/catch, the value of "time" is not recorded? So it returns only the initial value of "time" which is "null"? Or maybe a firewall problem?

Comment: can it be a problem of different language of windows used?